# Is something like window.onload OR window.onresize then do this function possible?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that should be called either on load or on resize.
Is it possible to combine it somehow?

```
var loadOrNotImages = function() {
   if(window.innerWidth > 640) {
     var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.img--only-on-high-reso');
     for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        imgs[i].src = imgs[i].attributes["data-src"].value;
        imgs[i].alt = imgs[i].attributes["data-alt"].value;
     }
   }
}

window.onload = function(){
   loadOrNotImages();
}

window.onresize = function() {
   loadOrNotImages();
}
```

Comment: sadly, no. what you're currently doing is the best way to do it right now

Comment: `onload` happens only once. is `onresize` also getting invoked at `onload` for you?

Comment: You don't need the wrappers. `window.onload = loadOrNotImages;` (or better yet, in the modern world, `window.addEventListener("load", loadOrNotImages);`

Comment: You don't need to combine them. There is nothing wrong with having two event listeners like those.

Comment: @gurvinder372, I think no.

Comment: @Dmitriy In that case, what you have is fine.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, rewrote it like this:`window.addEventListener("load", loadOrNotImages);
window.addEventListener("resize", loadOrNotImages);`

Comment: Thank you guys. After second thinking, the question looks silly now :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with how you're doing it now except you don't need the wrappers, just:

```
window.onload = loadOrNotImages;
window.onresize = loadOrNotImages;
```

...or even

```
window.onload = window.onresize = loadOrNotImages;
```

...or better yet, in the modern world, use `addEventListener`.

The DOM itself doesn't have a function for hooking up a function to multiple events at once. You could readily give yourself one:

```
function on(target, eventNames, handler) {
    eventNames.split(" ").forEach(function(eventName) {
        target.addEventListener(eventName, handler);
    });
}
```

then

```
on(window, "load resize", loadOrNotImages);
```